# IAR EWARM, virtual section out of flash, how to debug without flashing virtual segment

Tags: c, iar, flash-memory

My STM32F401VB MCU has 128KB flash @0x08000000. I have defined a section @ 0x09000000 to keep static color images, so the compiled executable has:
- 128KB @ 0x08000000 (embedded flash)
- 16MB @ 0x09000000 (SPI flash N25Q)
A custom loader running in a computer sends this executable hex image to the MCU, and my custom bootloader running in MCU flashes data:
- @ 0x08000000 in embedded flash
- @ 0x09000000 in SPI flash
My application checks every image address and it reads from embedded flash or SPI flash accordingly.

The problem is debugging, when I start debugging IAR IDE programs embedded flash @0x08000000 and SPI flash contents @ 0x09000000, but MCU has nothing in this address, I don't know how to program the embedded flash and ignore the data outside embedded flash (or program both memories, embedded and SPI).

Removing images is not an option because the application needs to know image addresses to read them from SPI flash. Images won't be modified but application is modified many times every day and I need to debug as easy as possible.

What is the best approach to debug an application using images in SPI flash?.

Best regards and thank you in advance.

Comment: You can define different linker script with different profile. Prepare your SPI flash with data in "relese profile", I mean with bootloader. Then use "debug profile" with a linker that maps 128KB only.

Comment: @LPs In this case the application compiled with "debug profile" does not know the images exist in SPI flash, should I read map file and define image names as numbers instead of arrays?. For example, Image1 is an array placed by linker at address 0x09000000 in release profile, but it will be "#define Image1 0x09000000" in debug profile. ok?

Comment: I have no means to tell you something specific to your needs. I'm sure your code could not address/map directly an external SPI memory. So you must use functions that makes the images accessible to do your job without mapping them with linker. I guess linker is only a way to merge images to binary file. Your bootloader does the magic, sending addresses higher than 0x09000000 to SPI mem.